# How to lower the requirements for a WPF app Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, setup-project

1. I created a WPF app
2. I changed its framework to 3.5 Client Profile
3. I created a Visual Studio Setup project
4. I added the WPF app output to the Setup project
5. I even changed the Setup project prerequisites to require only the 3.5 version
6. When I try to use the Setup on a fresh Windows 7 machine it tells me:

> This setup requires the .NET Framework version 4.0

How to make it run without installing the 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at http://rakesh-moss2007.blogspot.com/

> In the setup project, double click on Microsoft Net Framework under Detected Dependencies. Now open the properties of Net Framework, and select any framework less than 4.0.